# KeyError: <Figure size 720x432 with 0 Axes>

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here's a portion of my code (most of it is being omitted):

How do I address or resolve this issue?

KeyError: 'Loss ($M)' Figure size 720x432 with 0 Axes

What does that error message even mean? I'm new to Python, so please explain it in very basic terms that anyone can understand.

For my libraries, I'm using:
import matplotlib
from matplotlib  import pyplot as plt

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
plt.hist(df["Loss ($M)"], bins = 25, color = c, normed = True)
plt.xlabel("Incurred Loss ($M)", fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel("N", fontsize = 12)
plt.title("Loss Severity Distribution", fontsize = 14)
```

KeyError: 'Loss ($M)' 
Figure size 720x432 with 0 Axes>

Answer (score 1):

`KeyError: 'Loss ($M)' Figure size 720x432 with 0 Axes>`

Those are really two completely independent messages. The first, and important one is

```
KeyError: 'Loss ($M)'
```

It means you have no column named `"Loss ($M)"` in your dataframe `df`.

The second is just a consequence. It's not even an error, just the string representation of the figure you created. Obviously, it reports about the figure having no axes, because the command that should have plotted something failed due to the key error.